# setInterval срабатывает один раз

Tags: javascript

почему setInterval срабатывает один раз? То есть, в $scoreApp я вижу четверку и на этом все...

```js
var $buttonStart = document.querySelector('button');
var $scoreApp = document.querySelector('span');

$buttonStart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let countScore = 5;
    var startApp = setInterval(function(){
        if(countScore === 0){
            // Code
        } else {
            $scoreApp.textContent = countScore - 1;
        };
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
  <div class="container col-lg-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Вперед</button>
    <span></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что срабатывает всего один раз?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы заходите в else каждую секунду, вы не переписываете переменную. при проходе таймера 
переменная всегда равна 5 а не 4 потом 3 потом 2 и т.д.
Результат вычесления помещаеться в $scoreApp.textContent, а не изменяет саму переменную countScore

```
if(countScore === 0){
        // Code
    } else {
        $scoreApp.textContent = countScore - 1;
    };
```

Comment: } else {
            $scoreApp.textContent = countScore--; 
        };

Почему вот так работает?

Comment: @luckydev, а почему так не должно работать?

Comment: countScore-- тут сначало происходит отнимание а потом выполнение.